# What is the best practice using Logger in Iphone App

Tags: ios, error-logging

We have developed an iPhone App. Once we go live, if our customers come back and tell us that something crashed or does not work in their iPhone , then how do we debug ? In the web application, I would ask my server administrator to provide the log files. What do we do with the iPhone application when there is no server error, but something failed in the phone. Is there a way to get logs from the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Use [crashlytics](https://crashlytics.com/). You get automated crash reports, and you can filter by version.

You can add log statements that appear with your crashes in crash reports.

I've used it in production for iOS and android apps, and it's great.